# Visual Basic Script to Log into a website then go to another webpage - worked, now errors out?

Tags: html, vbscript

I wrote a basic script (very little experience) to open Internet Explorer, log in, then go to a website within the site (search).  It worked for a year, but now it doesn't work and I don't know why.

If I remove the code that navigates to the internal search it works.  So, the login works, but the redirection causes an error.  I thought it must be something in the website that changed, but if I do it manually (meaning manually type in the website search - after I've logged in with the script) it works, so I don't see how it could have stopped working.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
function run()
     IE.Visible = True
     IE.Navigate "https://pennsylvania.pmpaware.net/login"
     Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("auth_key").value = "USERNAME"
    .getElementByID("password").value = "PASSWORD"
    Wait IE
    .getElementsByName("commit").Item(0).Click
    Wait IE
    IE.Navigate "https://pennsylvania.pmpaware.net/rx_search_requests/new"
  End With
End function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Set autoIt = CreateObject("AutoItX3.Control")
  Do
    autoIt.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    autoIt.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub


Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

I just wanted to have the script log into the website (which works) and then open the search page.  It was used by many of my colleagues for over a year and it's very frustrating that it stopped working.  I really appreciate people taking a look at it and trying to help me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to post a comment so I apologize this is in the answer section, but I took your code (see below) and it seems to work. The key difference is that I'm not passing valid credentials but I do receive the error that I do not have permission. I added another website thereafter to make sure it can navigate after trying and failing and the script can navigate to something different. I did add a simplified 'Wait()' function.

Believe it or not, it simply could be the Wait(ie) function. So you may try the Wait() I added which eliminates the added parameters.

If the 'Wait()' doesn't help, I think either the url may have changed or there may be a new security protocol setup by your IT personnel since this is navigated to through credentials. This could be a firewall, Antivirus or other security software issue.

```
Option Explicit
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.visible = true
IE.Navigate "https://pennsylvania.pmpaware.net/login"
Wait()
With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("auth_key").value = "USERNAME"
    .getElementByID("password").value = "PASSWORD"
    Wait()
    .getElementsByName("commit").Item(0).Click
    Wait()
    IE.Navigate "https://pennsylvania.pmpaware.net/rx_search_requests/new"
 End With

Wait()

IE.Navigate "www.equip.org"

Sub Wait()
    do while IE.Busy
        Wscript.Sleep 500
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help.  I tried increasing the wait times without success.  I also tried to use your wait subroutine, but it gave me an error and wouldn't run the script.  Interestingly, if I take out the second step, going to the patient search page, the script logs me on.  I do agree it must be something with my wait subroutine.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. I, or someone else, may be able to offer the correct solution or stir you in the right direction if you can provide the error(s) you are receiving. If you cannot attach a screen shot then word-for-word will help if you need to type them. They can be cryptic but they are useful. I'm not fully convinced it is your script yet.